How to upload an embedding in FieldValue
I am trying to update a doc {embedding: FieldValue.vector(embeddingVector)}, where embeddingVector is [-0.013117947,    -0.037503175, -0.0040925546,  -0.010280714...]
I get:

Error: Update() requires either a single JavaScript object or an alternating list of field/value pairs that can be followed by an optional precondition. Value for argument "dataOrField" is not a valid Firestore document. Couldn't serialize object of type "VectorValue" (found in field "embedding"). Firestore doesn't support JavaScript objects with custom prototypes (i.e. objects that were created via the "new" operator).

I followed documentation, but error persist.
I tried to load a vector value for the "new" Firebase Firestore vector search but getting an update error.
import { config } from "../config.js"
import {
  FirestoreOnWriteProcess,
  FirestoreOnWriteProcessor,
} from "@invertase/firebase-extension-utilities"
import { FieldValue } from "@google-cloud/firestore"
import { embeddingClient } from "./client/index.js"
import * as functions from "firebase-functions"

const embed = async (input) => {
  await embeddingClient.initialize()
  const text = input[config.inputField]
  let embedding
  try {
    embedding = await embeddingClient.getSingleEmbedding(text)
  }
  catch (e) {
    console.error("Error fetching embeddings:", e)
    throw new Error("Error with embedding")
  }

const embeddingVectorAsArray = embedding.slice(); // Convert to a plain JavaScript array
const embeddingValue = FieldValue.vector(embeddingVectorAsArray);


  return { [config.outputField]: embeddingValue }
}

const batchEmbedFn = async (docs) => {
  await embeddingClient.initialize()
  const embeddings = await embeddingClient.getEmbeddings(
    docs.map(doc => doc[config.inputField]),
  )
  if (config.vectorStoreProvider === "firestore") {
    return embeddings.map(embedding => ({
      [config.outputField]: FieldValue.vector(embedding),
    }))
  }
  else {
    return embeddings.map(embedding => ({
      [config.outputField]: JSON.stringify(embedding),
    }))
  }
}

const shouldBackfill = (data) => {
  return data[config.inputField] && typeof data[config.inputField] === "string"
}

export const embedProcess = new FirestoreOnWriteProcess(embed, {
  id: config.instanceId,
  fieldDependencyArray: [config.inputField],
  shouldProcess: (_oldData, newData) =>
    !!newData[config.inputField]
    && typeof newData[config.inputField] === "string",
  shouldBackfill,
  batchFn: batchEmbedFn,
  batchSize: embeddingClient.batchSize,
})

const shouldUpdate = (data) => {
  const hasValidInput
    = data[config.inputField] && typeof data[config.inputField] === "string"

  const hasExistingOutput = data[config.outputField]

  return hasValidInput && hasExistingOutput
}

export const updateEmbedProcess = new FirestoreOnWriteProcess(embed, {
  id: config.instanceId,
  fieldDependencyArray: [config.inputField],
  shouldBackfill: shouldUpdate,
})

const embedOnWriteProcessor = new FirestoreOnWriteProcessor({
  processes: [embedProcess],
  statusField: config.statusField,
})

export const handleEmbedOnWrite = (
  change,
) => {
  return embedOnWriteProcessor.run(change)
}


Please edit the question to show a complete minimal reproducible example of the code that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to reproduce the problem using the code and instructions you provide.

You have a line import * as functions from "firebase-functions", but you never use functions anywhere.  Are you actually running this code in Cloud Functions, or doing something else?

I am running it as a function, that was just there for logger that I have taken out. The import should not be there

So how would we run this code for ourselves?  And we don't see your embeddingClient so we don't know how that works.  I suggest modifying this down to the absolute minimum and complete code that causes the error, maybe something that could be run as a nodejs program on the command line.
